# How to hide python version from being displayed when sending request to a py webserver

Tags: python-2.7, webserver

I've been running few py webservers in my host. A request to the host, has useful information like the python version in its response header.

For example, lets take websockify,

A curl request to the port return with

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: WebSockify Python/2.7.5
< Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 00:13:59 GMT
```

How do I hide the python version details in the headers?

Comment: You should provide a code example of your running server. Usually you can modify the headers of the server, simply by adding new ones (eg here: add a new `Server` header).

Comment: Its a websockify server. Its a pip installed program.